# Rails array to javascript in HighCharts, Highstock, 2 dimensional array

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts

In my app users record their weight and the date that weight belongs to. I want that data displayed in a HighStock line graph. Should be very simple, but I've been working on this (partially) over the past 2 months. I've looked at a bunch of different things and I can't get this to work.

The exact data I'd like displayed is the actual line in the line graph to be their weight, y-axis will be their weight, x-axis will be the date that the user entered for that weight.

i.e. user enters their weight in the form for yesterday as 135 and the date they put in with the form is 12/3/2012.

Don't know if it matters but a User has_many weights, a weight belongs_to a user.

Here is what I have and I'm getting a bunch of different errors. I'm definitely missing/not understanding something here:

Weight Model:

```
class Weight < ActiveRecord::Base

 def user_weight_series(user, weight)
  weights_by_weight_date = Weights.select("date(weight_date) as dater, content as   weights")
   weights_by_weight_date.map do |record|
parts = %w[%Y %m %d].map{ |s| record.dater.send(s) }
"[Date.UTC(#{parts.join(',')}), #{record.weights}]"
  end
end
```

application.html.erb

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    var chart;
     $(document).ready(function() {
    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'weight_chart',
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 20,
            marginBottom: 25
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Your Weight Over Time',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Weight'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },

        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },

        scrollbar: {
          enabled: true
        },

        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },


        series: [{
            tickInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
            pointStart: <%= 3.weeks.ago.at_midnight.to_i * 1000 %>,
            name: 'Weight',
            data: [ <%= current_user.user_weight_series(user, weight).join(", ") %> ],

        }]
    }, 

    function(chart){

        // apply the date pickers
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('input.highcharts-range-selector', $('#'+chart.options.chart.renderTo))
                .datepicker()
        },0)


    });
});

});
```

What's the best way to do this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have not worked with Ruby but Yes With Highstock. Can you generate sample fiddle with data Or Provide errors you are getting

Comment: How your data looks like?

Comment: @sebastian Not quite sure what you mean. I have 2 columns in a database table: weight, and weight date (the date the weight was entered). I need to grab that data using rails code and put it into a 2 dimensional array to display properly in a highstock chart.

Comment: In data I mean what you receive / print in series -> data in line 

            data: [ <%= current_user.user_weight_series(user, weight).join(", ") %> ]

Comment: When it's like this it throws up an exception so I can't really see what is being printed.

What I want it to look like is [[2-4-2013, 211], [2-7-2013, 210], [2-7-2013, 205]] in a form that can be used in highstock

Answer (score 0):

Here is the process I use, along with some tips to get you started:

1. Work backwards from the desired display you want to create, using dummy json data to populate the chart.
2. Figure out how to create a ruby hash of your real database data that matches the dummy json data series. For the timestamps, convert them to a highcharts-readable format like this:

   ```
   SOME_DATE.to_time.to_i * 1000
   ```
3. Have one of your controllers render the resulting ruby hash as json.

   ```
   def some_controller_method
     @chart_data_series = [] // your desired series here

     respond_to do |format|
       format.json { render :json => @chart_data_series }
     end
   end
   ```
4. Read this json from its appropriate page and pass it into your chart series. One way is to use [d3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_json):

   ```
   function buildChart(){
     d3.json("/path/to/your/data.json", function(error, json_data) {

       $('#chart_container').highcharts({
           chart: {type: 'column'}, 
           // options, options, etc
           series: json_data,
           // options, options, etc
       });

     });
   });
   ```